# App installed using snap but it is not shown in bin folder

Tags: command-line, 18.04, snap

I installed intellij idea using below command

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

but it not shown in bin folder inside `~/snap`. And how to open intellij idea using terminal?

Comment: intellij-idea-community

Comment: is it in the snap folder?

Answer (score 7):

It is installed in `/snap/bin/intellij-idea-community`

And you run it by `intellij-idea-community`

[image]

```
$ sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
intellij-idea-community 2019.3.3 from jetbrains✓ installed

$ which intellij-idea-community 
/snap/bin/intellij-idea-community

$ intellij-idea-community 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

For server, without gui, you'll get:

```
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```